# Minimize the Frobenius norm between two matrices with inequality and equality constraints.

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, programming

I had previously asked a question in which the problem was incorrectly specified. I am rephrasing it in this new question. The specific model is this one:

Let A $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and B and C $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, all of them known. Let${\Vert\cdot\Vert}_F$ be the Frobenius norm of a matrix. Let X $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ a matrix of unknowns and m>n.

\begin{align*}
\text{min} \quad & \lVert X-A\rVert^2_F \\
\text{sujeto a} \quad & X*C = I \\
& \forall i,j \in \{1,2,...,n\}, (B*X)_{ij} \geq 0 \\
& \forall j \in \{1,2,...,n\}, \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_{ij} = 1
\end{align*}

It would also be interesting to be able to approximate the solution in a case of nxn matrices.

How can I solve this?.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is unlikely that this problem has a closed form solution. However, it seems like this should be solvable via [convex optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization)

Comment: This is a quadratic program.

Comment: How can I transform de objetive function in a quadratic form?